# Dynamically or programatically created text box values occurs extraneously on changing native drop downs in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I created native  drop down(UIButton+UITableview) and text fields programatically.Inside the method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

If I changed drop down values the text box values has been setting extraneously on other text boxes.

**Image 1)**

[image]

**Image 2)**

[image]

1.First Image:In the First Image I entered the text box values 1,1,1 manually.During that time,first drop down having same values.

2.Second Image:In the second image If I change the drop down values.Extraneous text box values has been generated.(compare first and second image).

So, How to rectify this error.

My code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (tableView == self.tblview)
{
//Buttons created programatically
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
[btn1setTitle:projectDD forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview:btn1];
[btn1 addTarget:selfaction:@selector(proDropDwon:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn1 setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setTag:indexPath.row];
//Text field or text box created programatically.
UITextField *text1 =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0f,5.0f,50.0f,20.0f)];
[text1 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[cell addSubview:text1];
[text1 setTag:indexPath.row];
[text1 addTarget:self action:@selector(text1Change:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[text1 setText:text1];
int  j= 100;
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
UITextField *text2 =  [[UITextField alloc] init];
text2.frame = CGRectMake(j,5.0f,25.0f,20.0f);
[text2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[cell addSubview:text2];
[text2 setTag:indexPath.row];
[text2 setAccessibilityLabel:txtIndValue];
[text2 addTarget:self action:@selector(text2Change:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[text2 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
j = j + 35;
}
return cell;
}
```

Similarly, I created btn2 and btn3 for other 2 drop downs.

My code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath:I thought problem because of reloading.So I put code regarding tableviews.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self.tblview beginUpdates];
[self.tblview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tblview   indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tblview endUpdates];
[self.tblview reloadData];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Code for btn1 is clicked:

```
- (IBAction)proDropDown:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *) sender;
self.projIndexPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", btn1.tag];
if (self.tblviewProject.hidden ==YES) {
self.tblview1.hidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.tblview1];
}
else {
self.tblview1.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

Till now, I tried reloading the tableview inside btn1 clicked, commenting the reload data.where I have to do code changes in cellForRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath.or values setting inside button.Please Suggest me ideas.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your approach.

1. When reusing the cell, you are creating the button programmatically every time and adding into the context view. So you are eventually accumulating a lot of controls on a single view.Instrument your code and you should see memory hiking up.
   To overcome, you can add controls only when a new cell is created. Assuming you have only one type of cell this would hold good.
2. Since you have fixed controls is each cell, its better to design a static custom cell, which would make your job less complex.
3. The code for button click "proDropDwon"/"proDropDwon" does not match. This would cause runtime exception.
4. This statement is weird and this is mostly likely the cause of your issue. 
   `[text1 setText:text1];` text1 being a textfield cannot be assigned to text property.

with 3 and 4 It seems the code you have posted is not actual code where you are facing issues. Can you give the relevant code?